# Custom loss function

Tags: machine-learning, regression, predictive-modeling

Is it possible to apply a custom loss function in a regression model (or any other algorithm for predicting continuous variable) ? I'm working on a stock market prediction model and I need to maximize the following loss function: if [predicted] < [actual]  then [predicted] else [-actual]. Would that be possible ?
Thanks

Comment: If $[predicted] \ge [actual]$, then the loss does not depend on your prediction. This does not seem like a desirable property for a loss function to have.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a loss function comes from decision theory. Although there are some 'classic' loss functions the point is to be subjective, in the sense of being flexible enough to represent any particular problem conctext. So in that sense, yes, loss functions can be customised.
One of the main ways this has been achieved is via Bayesian regression, as the output of Bayesian regression is a probability distribution which can then the input for a loss function. This blog post shows the mechanics in a simple way (texts for Bayesian statistics and decision are often non-accessible), and also gives some examples of somewhat 'custom' loss functions in 'Examples: Part 3'. -> http://www.statsathome.com/2017/10/12/bayesian-decision-theory-made-ridiculously-simple/

Answer (score 0):

[Loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function)

> For most optimization algorithms, it is desirable to have a loss function that is globally continuous and differentiable.
>   
> *Two very commonly used loss functions are the squared loss and absolute loss. However, the absolute loss has the disadvantage that it is not differentiable at 0. The squared loss has the disadvantage that it has the tendency to be dominated by outliers*

**In your case** - You must convert your need into a function with the above property.

In addition to above point, another point to check - 

You current loss function will not follow the correlation i.e. **"Lesser Loss => Good prediction"**. 

 e.g. *y_pred = 500, 1000, 2000 and y_pred = 499, 999, 1999*. 

Prediction is accurate still your loss will be very high i.e. *499, 999, 1999*

Comment: How can I possibly convert my if statement to a continuous and differentiable function ?

Comment: Also, I don't insist on applying regression to this problem. Can it be handled by some other algorithm ?